# contentInset on SwiftUI's List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Is there a way how to set `contentInset` on SwiftUI's `List`? I need to adjust the bottom inset to have the last item visible above the bottom button.

[image]

My current solution is the following

`Section(header: Color.clear.frame(height: 64)) { EmptyView() }`

but I wonder is there a better way?

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: can share your reproducible  code ?

Comment: How he is going shake 150 reputation while he is 137, how is it possible?

Comment: @swiftPunk The bounty was started by another user - you can see the full history by accessing the post [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63887188/timeline). And btw you pay the bounty cost *upfront*. Also see [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Answer (score 23):

For a floating button, you can use `.safeAreaInset` on the `List`. The button will stay pinned to the bottom and the list will scroll and give it appropriate padding.

```
List {
    ForEach((0...20), id: \.self) { row in
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
    }
}
.listStyle(.inset)
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
    Button {
        //Button Action
    } label: {
        Text("Button")
            .font(.title3)
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red)
            .cornerRadius(16)
    }
}
```

[List inset at bottom with floating button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L70jV.png)

Answer (score 12):

My solution to your problem looks similar with [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887188/contentinset-on-swiftuis-list/66050932#66050932)'s answer but his answer will not show the `Button` at the top of the view since the `Button` is at the last section's footer in the `Form`. (`Button` will not be visible if you don't scroll to bottom.)

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
  
  let stringArray: [String] = [String](repeating: "Example", count: 30)
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
      List {
        ForEach(0..<stringArray.count) { stringIndex in
          Section {
            Text(stringArray[stringIndex])
          }
          
          if  stringIndex == stringArray.count - 1 {
            Spacer()
              .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
              .listRowBackground(
                colorScheme == .light ?
                  Color(.secondarySystemBackground) :
                  Color(.systemBackground)
              )
          }
        }
      }
      .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
      
      Button(action: {}) {
        Label("ADD NEW ITEM", systemImage: "plus")
      }
      .foregroundColor(.white)
      .font(.headline)
      .frame(height: 64)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      .background(Color.red)
      .cornerRadius(5)
      .padding(.horizontal)
    }
  }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: @LukasHromadnik is this the correct answer? if so could u please mark as an accepted for others benefits?

Answer (score 2):

Possible simple solution is just to use `footer` of last Section.

Below is a standalone demo (of course styles you can tune as you need). Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoButtonInLastSection: View {
    let data = Array(repeating: "some", count: 20)

    var body: some View {
      Form {
        ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { i in
          Section(footer:
            Group {
                if i == data.count - 1 {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .overlay(
                              Label("ADD NEW ITEM", systemImage: "plus")
                               .foregroundColor(.white))
                    }
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(height: 64)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }

        ) {
            Text("Item \(i)")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.listRowInsets` for defining last row content insets.

Sample code snippet below:

```
struct AddButtonInLastSection: View {
    var data = [[1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { dict in
                    ForEach(0 ..< dict.keys.count) { i in
                        Section(header: Text("Item \(dict.keys[dict.index(dict.startIndex, offsetBy: i)])")
                        ) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< dict.values.count) { j in
                                ForEach(dict.values[dict.index(dict.startIndex, offsetBy: j)], id: \.self) { k in
                                    if dict.keys[dict.index(dict.startIndex, offsetBy: i)] == 3 {
                                        if k == 6{
                                            Text("Items: \(k) last")
                                                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 16, leading: 20, bottom: 64, trailing: 0))
                                        }else {
                                            Text("Items: \(k)")

                                        }
               
                                    } else {
                                        Text("Items: \(k)")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(action: {}) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                    .overlay(
                        Label("ADD NEW ITEM", systemImage: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(.white))
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(height: 64)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that when you allow selection of item, then selection of last item will look taller than the other selections

Answer (score 1):

#### Overview

- You could add a `toolbar`, that way you don't have to worry about content inset.
- The toolbar would always stay on top and contents would scroll below the toolbar
- Inset is automatically taken care of

#### Screenshot:

[image: Toolbar with button]

#### Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                    Text("Item \(index)")
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button(action: doSomething) {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                                Text("Button")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 48)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
        }
    }

    private func doSomething() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

```
var body: some View {

    // Use this
    UICollectionView.appearance().contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0)
        
        return ZStack {
            List {
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: CAVEAT: Although this works, it affects all the lists.

Answer (score -9):

Try using the below code

```
.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 64, right: 0)
```

Comment: Did you even read the question? It's how to set the contentInset on a SwiftUI view not a UIKit view.